# Netgear WNDR3700 2.4GHz and 5GHz Wi-Fi are segregated

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have a Netgear WNDR3700 with both the 2.4GHz (B/G/N) and 5GHz (A/N) broadcasting. I'd assumed that devices connecting on either channel would work together without issues, but there are some devices (such as my iPhone 4 or HP wireless printer) that will only connect at 2.4GHz, and some that connect at 5GHz. However, it seems that they're segregated on the network, so a computer at 5GHz can't print to the printer, but the iPhone can.

This is causing issues not just with printing, but with Apple TV and so on. Is there a way to have the router let these devices all talk to each other?

Comment: The default configuration for the WNDR3700 allows precisely this, and is how it works with my one.  I didn't think it was even possible to segregate them this way.  Can you ping devices connected to different radios?

Answer (score 2):

It appears your device has its [Wireless/AP Isolation](http://forum1.netgear.com/showthread.php?t=54591) option enabled.

- NETGEAR (factory shipped) - `Setup` / `Wireless Settings` configuration page, disable checkbox `Wireless Isolation`.
- DD-WRT - `Wireless` / `Basic Settings` configuration page, disable `AP Isolation` option.

[image]

If you do not have access to your WNDR3700's configuration, I am not sure that you'll have any success improving your LAN connectivity.